# Nullable Types in .Net Programming Language

Tags: c#, .net

Recently while revising one of the concept I came across a situation which is interesting and I want to know why this happens.

We know one concept that we can't assign null values to Value types i.e. `Struct`, `int`, `DateTime`, etc.

In order to assign `null` we need nullable type i.e.

`int i` should be replaced with `Nullable<int> i = null`

But if we see `Nullable<T>` it is also of type `struct` then how come `null` can be assigned without stating any error? Why Microsoft contradicted it's own statement of "Null can't be assigned to value type"

If someone knows the reason behind this?

Comment: Your compiler knows what a nullable value type looks like.  It doesn't *actually* assign *null* to it.  Use ildasm.exe to see what it really does.

Answer (score 19):

Because `Nullable<T>` has compiler-level support; `null`, in the context of `Nullable<T>`, is essentially a value with a `HasValue` flag of `false`, where-as a non-null value has a `HasValue` flag of `true`. And similarly, "lifted" operators are derived from the defined operators. Likewise, `Nullable<T>` has *CLI* support, in terms of boxing: a boxed `Nullable<T>` with `HasValue` of `false` becomes `null`, not a new box instance.

Basically: it all just comes down to *because that is how they defined it should work*.

People wanted nullable value types: Microsoft figured out a way for that to happen.

Comment: Does it need "compiler level support?" I'd assume it could be implemented just by overriding the equality operators/methods of a standard struct (though it's entirely possible that there are some compiler optimisations...).  (I admit I've not looked at the IL/code for `Nullable` and probably should!)

Comment: @DanPuzey yes, it does; otherwise things like ` == null` / ` != null`, or any of the arithmetic etc operators: would not work. A regular struct is never null, for example.